# Variable in options

Tags: php

I got a problem i want to repeat a value his ow like
option1 = 1
option2 = 2

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Tijden-DB` WHERE klas='".$Klas."'");

       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
       $leraar = $row['Leraar'];
       }

echo '
<html>
    <form action="Afspraak2.php" method="post">
                <select name="klas">
                        <option>'.$leraar.'</option>
                    </select><br />
</html>
';
```

there are 2 rows but he replies only the last one

Comment: ***Notice:*** There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should print your options while iterating your records as follow

```
<html>
  <form action="Afspraak2.php" method="post">
    <select name="klas">
    <?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Tijden-DB` WHERE klas='".$Klas."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){           
       echo '<option>'.$row['Leraar'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select><br />
</html>
```